# InputStream.read() is either missing or adding a value in my buffer - How come?

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I've created the following procedure in the run() method of the ConnectedThread taken from the BluetoothChat sample.

```
// Read from the InputStream
byte[] buffer = new byte[16];
int offset = 0;
while(buffer.length-offset != 0)
{
    int bytesRead += mmInStream.read(buffer, offset, buffer.length-offset);
    offset += bytesRead;
}
// Do stuff with the contents of the buffer
```

The buffer is loaded in with 16 bytes gradually as expected but for some reason at the 10th byte in the array a 0 is inserted and shifts the remaining part of the package(and as such corrupting the entire package)

**Here is an example of what is happening**

The following is sent from the other client :

[-11, 126, -16, -30, -92, 110, -26, 13, 22, 91, -31, 32, 54, -125, -112, 45]

This is what I receive :

[-11, 126, -16, -30, -92, 110, -26, 13, 22, 91, **0**, -31, 32, 54, -125, -112]

As you can see, an extra 0 is pushed in as the 10th byte and the rest of the package is shifted to the right(cutting off the last byte)

As part of the debugging process we tried having a breakpoint at `bytesRead += mmInStream.read(buffer, offset, buffer.length-offset)` and to our surprise the **entire original message** was received. What gives?

How does the "break" in reads correct this issue? What am I doing wrong or not understanding?

Comment: It sounds like the client isn't *actually* sending what it thinks it's sending. By the way, your code would be clearer if you got rid of `isDone` and just changed to `while (offset < buffer.length)`. I'd also move the declaration of `bytesRead` into the loop.

Comment: That was our initial thought but how do you explain the "right" message being sent when a breakpoint is inserted into the loop?

Comment: If you're not reading anything until all the data has been received, possibly there's something wrong on the batching somewhere? Odd, I agree - it's definitely not a problem in this code though. You're doing the right thing.

Comment: You have an off by 1 error.  Your offset in the second read call is too high by one.  It works with the breakpoint because then all the data gets there and you read it in 1 call.  Of course it looks right to me-  the off by one error could be in your input stream class.

Comment: I suspected that as well. In our tests, however, the first read call only loaded a single byte into the buffer and the subsequent byte was loaded properly without incorrect offsetting.

Comment: AHA! There's your problem. See stefrank's answer below. That one-byte read exactly accounts for your off-by-one error. Maybe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably you meant

```
bytesRead = mmInStream.read(buffer, offset, buffer.length-offset);
offset += bytesRead;
```

instead of

```
bytesRead += ...
```

Comment: Fantastic! I don't have the application near me right now but this has to be it! Thank you! You'll get your flag as this being the correct tomorrow when I've tested it.

Answer (score 0):

Throw it all away and use `DataInputStream.readFully().`